# Tools for Visualising Algorithms

Tags: string, algorithm, visualization, matching

I would like to develop some visualisations for various string matching algorithms. Ideally, once the visualisation has been developed, I should be able to interact with it, for instance, by experimenting with different inputs to see how it affects the algorithm. Can anyone suggest what would be the best tool to use to create these visualisations?

I've been told that Mathematica is a tool that could be used with visualising algorithms, has anyone had much experience in doing this? How well suited would Mathematica be for visualising a string matching algorithm?

Comment: That would greatly depend on the algorithm, and what you're interested about in the algorithm itself (e.g. operation, complexity, speed, memory...). However, requests to 'find the best tool for...' are off topic on SO.

Comment: @tearfulheart, why do you want to visualize the algorithms? You might want to look at http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html to see what they did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can code in javascript, [d3.js](http://d3js.org) is an amazing data visualization library.

Here's an example of a visualization of an algorithm to [generate Hamiltonian graphs](http://christophermanning.org/projects/building-cubic-hamiltonian-graphs-from-lcf-notation/). It was built using d3.

Here's another example visualizing [min-heap](http://www.benfrederickson.com/2013/10/10/heap-visualization.html) generation.

Comment: This looks great! Is it possible to use Javascript outside of web development though? As I'm not planning to do this as a web application.

Comment: Unfortunately d3.js is limited to the browser.

Comment: The d3 library is too amazing for me not to use, I'll just implement the visualisations for a browser! Thanks slider!

Answer (score 0):

you can find a lot of visualizations here:

http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stevenha/visualization/

source: Competitive Programming 3 by Steven Halim and Felix Halim